# How can I insert smiley faces into MySQL (  )

Tags: mysql, character-set, sql-injection

I'm on MySQL 5.5.21, and trying to insert the '\xF0\x9F\x98\x8A' smiley face character. But for the life of me, I can't figure out how to do it.

According to various forums which I've been reading, it is possible. But whenever I try it, the data just gets truncated.

```
mysql> INSERT INTO hour  (  `title`,   `content`,   `guid` ,  `published` , `lang` ,  `type` ,  
       `indegree` ,  `lon` ,  `lat` ,  `state` ,  `country` , `hour`  )   
       VALUES ( "title" ,  "content   content" ,  "guid" ,  1,  1,   
                     "WEBLOG",  1,  1,  1,  "state" ,  "country" ,  1 );
Query OK, 1 row affected, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                       |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x8A  ...' for column 'content' at row 1 |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'published' at row 1                                |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select LAST_INSERT_ID();
+------------------+
| LAST_INSERT_ID() |
+------------------+
|           687302 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from hour where id = 687302;
+--------+-------+----------+------+---------------------+
| id     | title | content  | guid | published           |
+--------+-------+----------+------+---------------------+
| 687302 | title | content  | guid | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+--------+-------+----------+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But my table definition is as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE `hour` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `content` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `guid` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `published` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `lang` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('WEBLOG','MICROBLOG') CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `indegree` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `lon` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `lat` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
  `country` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
  `hour` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` enum('MALE','FEMALE') CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_zone` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MEMORY AUTO_INCREMENT=687560 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=288
```

One can see that I'm using CHARSET=utf8mb4. Surely this corrects issues around the use of multi-byte characters?

Ok, so I didn't notice:

```
  `content` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
```

I've corrected that now, but still get funky results.

```
CREATE TABLE `hourtmp` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `guid` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `published` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `lang` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('WEBLOG','MICROBLOG') CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `indegree` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `lon` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `lat` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
  `country` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
  `hour` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` enum('MALE','FEMALE') CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_zone` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MEMORY AUTO_INCREMENT=687563 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=288 |

 mysql> INSERT INTO hourtmp  (  `title`,   `content`,   `guid` ,  `published` , `lang` ,  `type` ,  `indegree` ,  
 `lon` ,  `lat` ,  `state` ,  `country` , `hour`  )   VALUES ( "title" ,  "content   content" ,  
 "guid" ,  1,  1,   "WEBLOG",  1,  1,  1,  "state" ,  "country" ,  1 );
 Query OK, 1 row affected, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)

 mysql> show warnings;

 | Level   | Code | Message                                                                       |

 | Warning | 1366 | Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x8A  ...' for column 'content' at row 1 |
 | Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'published' at row 1                                |

 2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

 mysql> select * from hourtmp;
 +--------+-------+-----------------------+
 | id     | title | content               |
 +--------+-------+-----------------------+
 | 687560 | title | content ????  content |
 | 687561 | title | content ????  content |
 +--------+-------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: I'm obliterating all special characters in the application layer now, so it isn't so much of a problem for me. But, I would like to know if it's possible to somehow get the data in and out of MySQL.

Comment: Not a MySQL guy, but can't you specify `uft8` for the `TEXT` field as well

Comment: have you run set names utf8mb4; from your client before issuing the insert?

Comment: JNK,the text field is using the table default, in this case utf8mb4.

Comment: atxdba. Thanks for the suggestion, still comes out as ?, which presumably means corrupted. Damn those emoticons/decepticons ! ;)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I’ve recently written [**a detailed guide on how to switch from MySQL’s `utf8` to `utf8mb4`**](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#utf8-to-utf8mb4). If you follow the steps there, everything should work correctly. Here are direct links to each individual step in the process:

- [Step 1: Create a backup](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#backup)
- [Step 2: Upgrade the MySQL server](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#upgrade)
- [Step 3: Modify databases, tables, and columns](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#databases-tables-columns)
- [Step 4: Check the maximum length of columns and index keys](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#column-index-length)
- [Step 5: Modify connection, client, and server character sets](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#character-sets)
- [Step 6: Repair and optimize all tables](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#repair-optimize)

I suspect that your problem can be solved by following step 5. Hope this helps!

Comment: Have left that job so unable to test/verify. However I suspect that the collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci setting is what was missing. Good tutorial!

Comment: Very nice Mathias. A reminder to people, your client connection details matter. I'm using the NPM module `mysql` from Node, and needed to specify `charset: 'utf8mb4'` in my `createConnection()` call, otherwise inserting true UTF8 characters still failed with the `Incorrect string value` error, even after converting the table and column to `utf8mb4` character set and collation.  I expect your client config level details in Step 5 would have similar effect.

Answer (score 3):

**Do the Following things:**

1. Set the database charset to **utf8mb4**
2. Set the charset of column to **utf8mb4**

like below query:

```
ALTER TABLE `comments` CHANGE `text` `text` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Are these steps really sufficient? The accepted answer has many more.

Comment: Depends on what the problem was, if the problem was on the database side this is enough. But it can very well be a client connection problem too.

Answer (score 0):

In Node.js

1. Setup Mysql connection

```sql
const mysql = require('mysql');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword",
  charset : 'utf8mb4' // This mandatory to allow Emoji 
});
```

2. Set charaset of column to uft8mb4

```sql
ALTER TABLE your_table MODIFY your_column text
 CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```